# Read entire file into array

Tags: arrays, awk

I have a text file with 5000 lines, and every five lines can be grouped. In that group of five lines I want to replace the string in 12th column in 2nd line of each group. To accomplish this I need to read the entire file into an array in awk, but I couldn't do it. Please could anyone help me.

```
abc acd ade aef afg agh ahi aij ajk akl alm amn ano apq ars atu auv awx ayz
**abc acd ade aef afg agh ahi aij ajk akl alm *amn* ano apq ars atu auv awx ayz**
abc acd ade aef afg agh ahi aij ajk akl alm amn ano apq ars atu auv awx ayz
abc acd ade aef afg agh ahi aij ajk akl alm amn ano apq ars atu auv awx ayz
abc acd ade aef afg agh ahi aij ajk akl alm amn ano apq ars atu auv awx ayz
bcd bef bfg bhi bjk blm bno bpq brs btu bvw bxy bza bab bbc bdc bde bfg bhj
**bcd bef bfg bhi bjk blm bno bpq brs btu bvw *bxy* bza bab bbc bdc bde bfg bhj**
bcd bef bfg bhi bjk blm bno bpq brs btu bvw bxy bza bab bbc bdc bde bfg bhj
bcd bef bfg bhi bjk blm bno bpq brs btu bvw bxy bza bab bbc bdc bde bfg bhj
bcd bef bfg bhi bjk blm bno bpq brs btu bvw bxy bza bab bbc bdc bde bfg bhj
.....
.....
.....

BEGIN {
    FS="\t"
}

NR==FNR {
    a[FNR]=$0
    next
}
```

Comment: replace with what? and what have you tried till now?

Comment: Ignore this comment if you are doing this to study awk, but given the problem size it should be easy to do it in any other program. Say Excel.

Comment: Grouped how? Do you want to write each line into an array? `awk '/./{arr[i++] = $0}'` or do you want to write each group of five as an entry?

Comment: @sarathi I tried the above code, but I don't know how to loop thru the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
    FS="\t"
}

{
  if( NR % 5 == 2 ){ # 2nd line in each group
     for( i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i ++ ){ 
        # replace 12th column by a string, 
        # simply print everything else
        if( i == 12 ){
           printf "replacement" FS
        } else {
           printf $i FS
        }
        printf "\n"
     }
  } else {  # simply print all other lines in each group
     print
  }
}
```

I believe this is better than reading the entire file into an array, which is not really how you do such things in awk.

However, if you do wish to read the entire file into an array for some reason, this would be a solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
    FS="\t"
}

{
    for( i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i ++ ){
        a[NR,i] = $i
    }
}

END{
    for( i = 2 ; i <= NR ; i = i+5 ){
        a[i,12] = "replacement"
    }
    for( i = 1 ; i <= NR ; i++ ){
        j=1
        while( a[i,j] ){
            printf a[i,j] FS
            j ++
        }
        printf "\n"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be because of the tab-file separator that you seem to be using. I modified the code accordingly, see my edit. Both versions work for me on the example input you provided.

Comment: The above might have worked for a given sample input file but it contains bugs and is the wrong approach anyway. See @triplee's correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just assign to `$12` to change it.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }'
  NR % 5 == 2 { $12 = "ick" }1' inputfile >outputfile
```

Thanks to @EdMorton for the `BEGIN` block fix.